# Why am I getting incorrect values for my bit columns in a MySQL query when I join a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with what should be a very simple query, on the surface.

I am running the following query:

```
select
    dc1.deck_deckid,
    dc1.card_name,
    dc1.isCommander,
    dc1.isSideboard,
    c.card_text as text,
    c.card_manacost as manacost,
    c.card_cmc as cmc,
    c.card_colors as colors,
    c.card_types as types,
    c.card_subtypes as subtypes,
    c.card_supertypes as supertypes,
    c.card_produces_colors as produces_colors,
    dc1.quantity,
    c.card_power,
    c.card_toughness
from
    deckcard dc1
inner join
    card_digest c
on
    c.card_name = dc1.card_name
where
    dc1.deck_deckid = 'xxxxxxxxx'
group by
    dc1.card_name
```

This yields correct results for all fields **except** for the *dc1.isCommander* and *dc1.isSideboard* fields, which show **1** where they should show **0** (both are *bit(1)* fields).

I can get a correct result for the query is I do either of the following:

1. Remove the join to *card_digest*
2. Remove the *c.card_text* field from
   the query (type is *text*)

The MySQL version is 5.7.15, and I'm connecting using PHP mysqli 'libmysql - 5.5.50"

Can anyone give me a hint as to what's going on here? The problem has only started occurring recently - it's production code that was running fine when I last used the system about six weeks ago.

**Edit:** This query is now working as expected again, after changing the data type of *card_digest.card_text* to a *varchar(1024)*. No clue as yet as to what prompted the change in behaviour, but it appears that the root of the problem is the combination of *bit* and *text* fields in the join.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is probably not required

Comment: To clarify, there are some aggregated columns in the original query that I trimmed for the sake of brevity - their presence or lack of wasn't altering the result.

Comment: That kind of statement is liable to irritate the community. Well, it irritates me anyway.

Comment: I can only apologise if you find my statements irritating. The query above is the result of reducing the original query down to the minimum complexity possible whilst still preserving the unexpected behaviour.

In any case, I've found a workaround, by changing the type of the text column to a varchar(1024) - far from ideal, since I've got no solid guarantee that the source data will never contain text over that length (save for the amount of text that can be fitted in a physically printed text box of a fixed size), but it's gotten my site working again.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the data type of the *card_digest.card_text* field from *text* to *varchar(1024)* restored this query to working order, which is a viable workaround for now.

Still interested in knowing what underlying behaviour could cause this error, but the urgency is diminished.